# ApplicantEducation matching query does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

This function in views.py

**views.py**

```
    def UpdateEducation(request):
        context = {}
        user_obj = request.user
        if not user_obj.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('login')
    
        user_id = Applicant.objects.filter(app_id = user_obj.app_id).first()
        print(user_id)
        applicant = ProfileInfo.objects.filter(user=user_id).first()
        print(applicant)
        user_info = ApplicantEducation.objects.filter(applicant_info = applicant).get()
        if request.POST:
            form = EducationForm(request.POST, instance=user_info)
            if form.is_valid():
                obj = form.save(commit=False)
                obj.applicant_info = applicant
                print(obj)
                obj.save()
                return redirect('profile')
            else:
                form = EducationForm()
                context['education_form'] = form
        else:
            try:
                form = EducationForm(
                    initial={
                        'institute_name': user_info.institute_name,
                        'marks_percentage' : user_info.marks_percentage,
                        'affilation_with' : user_info .affilation_with,
                        'date_completion':user_info.date_completion,
                        'degree_details' : user_info.degree_details,
                    }
                )
                context['education_form']= form
            except:
                form = EducationForm()
                context['education_form']= form
        return render(request, 'admission/signup.html', context)
```

This model class i made for views.py
**models.py**

```
    class DegreeDetails (models.Model):
        degree_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        degree_category = models.CharField(max_length= 15)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return '%s %s'%(self.degree_name, self.degree_category)
    
    class ApplicantEducation(models.Model):
        applicant_info = models.ForeignKey(ProfileInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        degree_details = models.ForeignKey(DegreeDetails, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
        marks_percentage = models.FloatField(max_length=5, default=0.0)
        institute_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        affilation_with = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
        date_completion = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
```

This is the form class for the model.....
**forms.py**

```
    class EducationForm( forms.ModelForm):
        
        class Meta:
            model = ApplicantEducation
            fields = [
                'institute_name',
                'marks_percentage',
                'affilation_with',
                'date_completion',
                'degree_details',
            ] 
        def clean(self):
            if self.is_valid():
                institute_name = self.cleaned_data['institute_name']
                marks_percentage = self.cleaned_data['marks_percentage']
                affilation_with = self.cleaned_data['affilation_with']
                date_completion = self.cleaned_data['date_completion']
                degree_details = self.cleaned_data['degree_details']
```

This the error i got
**Error**

```
    ApplicantEducation matching query does not exist.
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/education/
    Django Version: 3.1.7
    Exception Type: DoesNotExist
    Exception Value:    
    ApplicantEducation matching query does not exist.
    Exception Location: C:\Users\cms.user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py, line 429, in get
    Python Executable:  C:\Users\cms.user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
    Python Version: 3.9.1
    Python Path:    
    ['D:\\Development\\cmsproject',
     'C:\\Users\\cms.user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
     'C:\\Users\\cms.user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Users\\cms.user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
     'C:\\Users\\cms.user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
     'C:\\Users\\cms.user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
     'C:\\Users\\cms.user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
    Server time:    Thu, 11 Mar 2021 05:03:04 +0000
```

The error exists in the below line of code.....
**user_info = ApplicantEducation.objects.filter(applicant_info = applicant).get()**

Anyone please take a look of this bug. The whole code is intended to store education details of user in the backend database....
Thank you and looking forward to your replies....

Comment: **user_info =  get_object_or_404(ApplicantEducation, applicant_info = applicant)** i have changed the buggy code to above line of code, it seems that there is something wrong with #GET Request, but i am unable to sort it out...... Anyone who can help??

Answer (score 0):

So few things:

```py
def UpdateEducation(request):
        context = {}
        user_obj = request.user
        if not user_obj.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('login')
```

can be replaced with:

```py
@login_required
def UpdateEducation(request):
        context = {}
```

Django decorators are here for that ;)

then replace this:

```py
user_info = ApplicantEducation.objects.filter(applicant_info = applicant).get()
```

with

```py
#if you can have multiple answers
user_info = ApplicantEducation.objects.filter(applicant_info=applicant)
#if you can have only one (unicity constraint)
user_info = ApplicantEducation.objects.get(applicant_info=applicant)
```

Finally the error comes because you try to get an unexisting AplicantEducation item. It seems that there is no AplicantEducation item linked to your aplicant

Comment: ApplicantEducation is the model and intended to store data from user input??

Comment: That is the thing I'm not sure to understand what you try to do. Maybe if you provide an explanation about the process you try to make, we will be able to answer better :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if request.POST:
        user_info = ApplicantEducation.objects.filter(applicant_info = applicant).first()
        form = EducationForm(request.POST, instance=user_info)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.applicant_info = applicant
            print(obj)
            obj.save()
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            context['education_form'] = form
    else:
        try:
            user_info = ApplicantEducation.objects.filter(applicant_info = applicant).get()
            form = EducationForm(#some values)
```

The problem was with post method, compare the two views.py, you will see the differenece.
Thank you